# APNS Save Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications

I am working on `iOS` notifications with `APNS`. I can send and receive notifications. I want to save this notifications on phone. For example my apps receives daily temperature status notification via `APNS` and this message like "temp: 25C 16.08.2016". I want to save this message in phone user defaults when notification receive. When user want to see past temperatures i want to show list include notification messages. List like;

16.08.2016 25C

15.08.2016 26C

14.08.2016 21C
.
.
.

Comment: Sounds about right, Whats the problem? You want to rearrange the stored String?

Comment: I dont know how can i save APNS notification messages.

Comment: How do you want to save them?  In a file?  In a memory structure like an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get it in `AppDelegate` in `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method from `userInfo`.

Answer (score -1):

In `appDelegate.m`

```
  - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
        //Handle notification when the user click it while app is running in background or foreground.
        //Get Custom field data 1618
        NSLog(@"%@",userInfo );
        if(application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive) {

            NSLog(@"Inactive - the user has tapped in the notification when app was closed or in background");
            //do some tasks


        }
        else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground) {

            NSLog(@"application Background - notification has arrived when app was in background");
    //do some tasks
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"application Active - notication has arrived while app was opened");
           //do some tasks

        }


    }
```